# Flask has a same funtion like spring @RequestMapping params

Tags: flask, flask-restful

Hi Everyone I'm just searching for the feature of Flask.

What I want to do is to branch controller with query-parameter like Spring @RequestMapping [EXAMPLE](https://dzone.com/articles/using-the-spring-requestmapping-annotation)

[image]

I want Flask Controller to work when specific params exist.
Do that features exist In Flask?

I don't want to branch with if statement in method

I dont want to like this.

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/user')
def user():
    actions = request.args.get('actions')
    if actions == "migration"
       pass
    if actions == "something"
       pass
     ....
```

I want to like this

```
@app.route('/user', params={"actions=migration"})
def user_migration():
    pass

@app.route('/user', params={"actions=something"})
def user_something():
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add that logic in your "controller" itself, like so:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/home/fetch')
def data():
    # here we want to get the value of user (i.e. ?personId=some-value)
    personId = request.args.get('personId')
    if personId == <your-value-here>
```

If you know what your params are always going to be then why not just set it to the route itself:

```
@app.route('/user/migration')
def user_migration():
    pass

@app.route('/user/something')
def user_something():
    pass
```

Comment: Does this not work for your needs?

Comment: No It works but I don't want to make many if statement in one controller